# How to submit iphone app in Appstore

Tags: iphone, xcode, submission

I am new to iphone app submission process.
My app name is health XY and i gave appdelegate file name as healthAppDelegate.h and  healthAppDelegate.m.Can anyone please tell me What name i have to give for Bundle Name, Bundle identifier, Bundle display name, Executable file, Bundle OS Type code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the Apple docs about this but I'll send you along the way.
BundleName = simply your app name
BundleID is usually your company name + app name, such as com.yourcompany.healthxy
executable file is done for you by Apple, also bundle os type code.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Info.plist programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009248-SW1

There are sections for:

CFBundleIdentifier, CFBundleName, CFBundleExecutable, CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundlePackageType

> Bundle display name: This is what you will see under your app icon on
>   the home screen.
>
> Bundle identifier: This should be unique to your
>   company. Your reverse domain name:  com.yourdomain would be good
>
> Bundle OS Type code: Is APPL on my apps
>
> Executable file: ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
>
> Bundle Name: ${PRODUCT_NAME} (found in your build settings, generated
>   from your target name)